# Java, list of class types

Tags: java, list, class, inheritance

I am working on a java application. The is an abstract class Model and 2 derived classes Model 1 and Model 2. Model1 and Model2 behave differently, so I want to allow the user to select a model from the two.
It can be implemented like:

```
Model model;
If(response==1){
    model = new Model1();
}else if(response==2){
    model = new Model2();
}
```

Now the problem with this is, that if I add a new class Model3, I have to rewrite the code.
I could create a List, where I would add an instance from each class, then I would add a static method, that would return a new Instance of the class, but I hope it can be done with bit a more style.

Is there possible to create a List, to hold the **type** of each class. From this List I could create a menu to select a model, and then use the type to create the class the user needs.

**So is it possible, to create a `List<Class>`, then use the Class object as a constructor, to create an instance of the given class?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a list of [suppliers](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html):

```
static final List<Supplier<Model>> MODEL_MAKERS = ImmutableList.of(
    new Supplier<Model>() { public Model get() { return new Model1(); } },
    new Supplier<Model>() { public Model get() { return new Model2(); } },
    new Supplier<Model>() { public Model get() { return new Model3(); } }
);
```

You could muck around with reflection, but that requires stepping outside Java's normal exception handling mechanisms, requires zero-argument `public` constructors and `public` classes which limits how code can change under maintenance in ways that aren't checked by `javac`, and just isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: +1 for not using reflection.  Sometimes you have to, though (if you don't know the class at compile time, for example)

Comment: @StevenSchlansker, I agree that there are uses for reflection.  I prefer to limit it to the boundaries between Java object systems and other systems -- the file system, ORMs, embedded scripting languages. If you're working entirely within Java, there's often a better way to use it that doesn't affect maintainers ability to refactor code, follow program flow, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that it will have a public no-args constructor, you can use [Class.newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29)

For more complicated uses, you can find a [Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html) object with [Class.getConstructor(s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) and then invoke it that way.

Once you have that, it is relatively easy to stick your `Class`es into a `Map` or something to do lookups and create instances.

Comment: Don't use `newInstance`.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) explicitly warns: "Note that this method propagates any exception thrown by the nullary constructor, including a checked exception. Use of this method effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that would otherwise be performed by the compiler."

Comment: In some cases that's exactly what you want.  It is definitely worth noting, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) method on Class to construct one. It has to have a no-args constructor though.

Comment: Don't use `newInstance`.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) explicitly warns: "Note that this method propagates any exception thrown by the nullary constructor, including a checked exception. Use of this method effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that would otherwise be performed by the compiler."

Comment: It's fine if you're confident the constructor won't throw an exception. If you never called anything that might throw an exception you'd never get any coding done... :-)

Comment: it's fine if you're confident the constructor won't throw an exception **now and under maintenance**.

Comment: I agree it's worth avoiding reflecting if you can, though.